# How to use JsonSerializerOptions to include related data

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have the below code. It works perfectly ok until related data is included using the Include syntax. However, if related data is included it gives Internal Server Error. Can you please help

```
 private async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetEnumerableDataAsyncBySend(string apiEndpoint, object[] parameters)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(ms, parameters);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiEndpoint);
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            using (var requestContent = new StreamContent(ms))
            {
                request.Content = requestContent;
                requestContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                using (var response = await _httpGatewayClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                        var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<TEntity>>(content, _options);
                        return data;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception($"Error getting data from {apiEndpoint}. Error status is {response.StatusCode}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

After reading through several articles I assume the issue is related to JSON Serialize options
This is what is set in the constructor class

```
            _options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
```

Comment: Please clarify what "related data is included using the Include syntax" (for classes used in SerializeAsync(ms, parameters)?). `POST apiEndpoint` probably requires this data?

Comment: Hello Graphwalk, The data is fetched from an API and consumed by an MVC project. Main Entity is Customer and the include is CustomerAddress. I debugged the API and ensure the related data is populated using the ".Include". But after this step, the debugger goes to the above function and response.IsSuccessStatusCode is false and the error is "InternelServerError". The same API function sends data without related data successfully.

Comment: Try to debug your API and step by step to debug the code, whether the API method is executed successfully, and the return data is correct? If possible, I suggest you could post the relate code about the API method.

Comment: Hello Zhi Lv, Thank you for your response. I tried debugging but no clue. I created another project with the relevant items and the same is published on GitHub. Please see or download the code and see whether you can help me. https://github.com/jpthomas74/JsonIncludeProblem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your sample and tried your api with include. It has this problem.

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected.
> This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger
> than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using
> ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.

To Fix this you need to ignore circular references. I don't have .net 6 with me. So I tried with .net5.

here is the solution

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
```

for .net6(haven't tried)

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
```

Other option: By the way I am not sure about performance about these two methods.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectDto, settings);
```

Comment: Thankyou cdev. You are a genius

Comment: One question to you cdev, I have several controllers and several functions in this API. Only one function needs to include related data. Is there a way to specify this setting separate for a request or this endpoint? Is there any performance disadvantages by adding the above statement in the startup class?

Comment: By the way, services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve); works fine ..NET5 and .NET6 and services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles); works fine in >NET6 preview

Comment: I added a work around if you want it only one place.